# Unexpected behaviour: Removing rows from data frame converts to vector R

Tags: r

I am seeing what seems like strange behavior in R: When I remove rows from a simple data frame, the object is transformed to a vector. Is this expected?

An example:

```
a = data.frame(x = 1:10) #create simple dataframe
> a
    x
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10 10

> class(a) #check its a dataframe
[1] "data.frame"

a <- a[-(1:2), ] #remove the first two rows from the dataframe

> a #check the rows are gone (but note result prints as a vector)
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

> class(a) #check the class to see that it is actually a vector
[1] "integer"

as.data.frame(a) #convert back to dataframe, and find that the name of the col is changed. 
   a
1  3
2  4
3  5
4  6
5  7
6  8
7  9
8 10
```

Losing the colname is a hassle when I am applying dplyr, where i lose the name entirely:

```
data.frame(x = 1:10) %>%
  .[-(1:2), ] %>%
  as.data.frame()
   .
1  3
2  4
3  5
4  6
5  7
6  8
7  9
8 10
```

I would expect:

```
   x
1  3
2  4
3  5
4  6
5  7
6  8
7  9
8 10
```

Is this expected? If so why, and how can I remove rows from a simple dataframe without losing colnames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `drop` as by default for `?Extract`

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

and the `drop` documentation says

> drop - For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension (see the examples). This only works for extracting elements, not for the replacement. See drop for further details.

`drop` is TRUE especially with `data.frame`.  But, that is not the case in `subset` or with `data.table` or `tibble`

```
a[-(1:2),, drop = FALSE] 
#    x
#3   3
#4   4
#5   5
#6   6
#7   7
#8   8
#9   9
#10 10
```

It is a case when there is a single column or row

---

With `tibble`, it wouldn't drop the dimensions

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(x = 1:10) %>% 
   slice(-(1:2))
# A tibble: 8 x 1
#      x
#  <int>
#1     3
#2     4
#3     5
#4     6
#5     7
#6     8
#7     9
#8    10
```

Or

```
tibble(x = 1:10)[-(1:2),]
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data.table(x = 1:10)[-(1:2)]
```